# deleting rows based on number of true values per group - Python

Tags: python, pandas, sum, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I am trying to delete rows based on groupby and number of True values. 
Per group, if they have only one true value (sum() = 1), I would like that single row deleted.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'value': [True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True]})

print (df) 
   id  value
0   1   True
1   1   True
2   1  False
3   2   True
4   2  False
5   2  False
6   3  False
7   3  False
8   3   True

df.groupby('id')['value'].sum()
Out[571]: 
id
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
```

id 1 & 3 match the criteria, but how do i delete those single true rows such that the dataframe then becomes:

```
print (df) 
   id  value
0   1   True
1   1   True
2   1  False
3   2  False
4   2  False
5   3  False
6   3  False
```

Comment: You mean ids 2 & 3 match the criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Boolean mask:

```
m1 = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('sum') == 1
m2 = df['value']

df = df[~(m1 & m2)].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)

   id  value
0   1   True
1   1   True
2   1  False
3   2  False
4   2  False
5   3  False
6   3  False
```